# Split string assignment

Tags: scala, playframework

In a Play template file I would like to split a string and assign each part to a variable. However, the following does not work:

```
@for(x <- a) {
   @defining(x.split("""\.""")) { Array(x1, x2) =>
      ...
   }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Use second argument of `split` to avoid MatchError on strings with several dots: `x.split("""\.""", 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the `case` keyword.

```
@for(x <- a) {
   @defining(x.split("""\.""")) { case Array(x1, x2) =>
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Well, that's not exactly a 'trick'. It's a language feature. If you want to pattern match the arguments, you use the `case` keyword.

Comment: I've sort of given up learning Scala properly since it's too complicated for me; not so much the concepts but the syntax and semantics. As I get older I value simplicity more and more.