# Play! + Scala: Split string by commnas then Foreach loop

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a long string similar to this:

```
"tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4"
```

Now in my play template I would like to create a foreach loop like this:

```
@posts.foreach { post =>
    @for(tag <- @post.tags.split(",")) {
        <span>@tag</span>
    }
}
```

With this, I'm getting this error: `')' expected but '}' found.`

I switched `)` for a `}` & it just throws back more errors.

How would I do this in Play! using Scala?

Thx in advance

---

With the help of @Xyzk, here's the answer: [stackoverflow.com/questions/13860227/split-string-assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860227/split-string-assignment)

Comment: Try to use `for` instead of `foreach` in the inner loop

Comment: @AlekseyIzmailov just tried, same result

Comment: `@for(tag <- @post.tags.split(","))` should be `@for(tag <- post.tags.split(","))`, and the outer loop should be a regular for loop: `@for(post <- posts)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this because the answer marked correct isn't necessarily true, as pointed out in my comment. There are only two things wrong with the original code. One, the `foreach` returns `Unit`, so it has no output. The code should actually run, but nothing would get printed to the page. Two, you don't need the magic `@` symbol within `@for(...)`.

This will work:

```
@for(post <- posts)
    @for(tag <- post.tags.split(",")) {
        <span>@tag</span>
    }
}
```

There is in fact nothing wrong with using other functions in play templates.

Comment: Actually you should avoid using to many functions in a play template. It is a good practice to prepare your data for rendering _before_ you pass it to the template. If you don't do that you will soon be doing business logic in your templates and that's the path to maintenance hell.

Comment: Fair enough. I meant "nothing wrong" in the context of compilation. But yes, I agree that you should minimize the amount of functions you use in templates.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the problem

```
@for(tag <- post.tags.split(",")) {
    <span>@tag</span>
}
```